# MongoDB connection with Spring Boot MongoTemplate gets interrupted by DNS change

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, google-app-engine

The app starts just fine when doing so locally but it seems that deployment of the app in GCP App Engine causes the MongoDB connection string to be resolved in some manner that interrupts the process and cause the application to fail.

```
2023-09-25 21:58:31 default[20230925t201537]  2023-09-25T21:58:31.234Z  INFO 11 --- [mb4.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-sub83tp-shard-00-02.qa74mb4.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-09-25 21:58:31 default[20230925t201537]  2023-09-25T21:58:31.260Z  INFO 11 --- [mb4.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-sub83tp-shard-00-01.qa74mb4.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2023-09-25 21:58:31 default[20230925t201537]  2023-09-25T21:58:31.263Z  WARN 11 --- [mb4.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread during notification of DNS resolution state change
2023-09-25 21:58:31 default[20230925t201537]  com.mongodb.MongoInterruptedException: Interrupted waiting for lock       at com.mongodb.internal.Locks.checkedWithLock(Locks.java:49) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]      at com.mongodb.internal.Locks.withLock(Locks.java:36) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]      at com.mongodb.internal.Locks.withLock(Locks.java:29) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.withLock(BaseCluster.java:275) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]      at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.withLock(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.updateDescription(BaseCluster.java:247) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]     at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.updateDescription(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:387) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]       at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.lambda$initialize$0(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:100) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.9.1.jar!/:na]
********
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

I searched and searched but it seems that most people encountered this error for other reasons such as not enabling any IP to access the database or attempting to deploy from a sandboxed instance.

I tried setting the connection string in various forms, such as a single whole string or a string with variable insertions but it gets treated all the same.

Edit: It seems this error is due to connections from Shared instances of MongoDB Atlas not being allowed from cloud providers. After changing my Cluster to a Serveless Instance I was able to connect from GAE.